# SQL запрос из текстового файла

Tags: sql, sql-server

Допустим есть процедура в которой мы объявили переменную

```
DECLARE @myquery VARCHAR(2000)
```

теперь я хочу записать в эту переменную запрос из текстового файла - "select * from ..."
Возможно ли такое в ms sql managemed studio?

```
declare @cmd  VARCHAR(2000);
declare @query VARCHAR(2000);
SELECT @query = SQLText FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'с:\new\SQL.txt', SINGLE_CLOB) AS Document(SQLText)
set @cmd = 'bcp.exe "' + @query + '" queryout C:\new\outxml.XML -w -r -T';
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

в текстовом файле

> select top(100) CadNo as КадастНомер, Name from EstateDG.dbo.Lot as
>   ЗУМО FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('СодФормДок'), Elements

Comment: Посмотрите эту статью - https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/

Comment: Как я понял текст запроса находится в текстовом файле? Запрос один или несколько? Если несколько то читать каждый отдельно, как разделены? В общем, можешь посмотреть в сторону OPENROWSET с параметром BULK.

Answer (score 2):

Если правильно понял:

```
DECLARE @myquery VARCHAR(2000)
SELECT @myquery = SQLText FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'с:\SQL.txt', SINGLE_CLOB) AS Document(SQLText)
```

Comment: а если несколько select, то нужно спец разделитель вставлять?

Comment: Тогда можно создать файл форматирования и в текстовом файле каждый запрос писать отдельной строкой. Либо парсить полученное значение в переменной, но тогда у тебя в переменную возможно не попадет полностью содержимое файла, т.к. длина переменной = 2000. Рекомендую почитать про [OPENROWSET (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms190312(v=sql.90).aspx)

Comment: не получается, создал документ, записал туда "select", пробую считать, следующая ошибка - Не удалось найти хранимую процедуру "select..."

Comment: Приведи код. Предполагаю, записал просто `select`, а кто напишет полный синтаксис select'а? И как ты выполняешь полученный в переменную запрос? `EXEC @myquery` ? Надо `EXEC(@myquery)`.

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: А запрос из текстового файла в ms sql managemed studio в таком виде нормально выполняется?